# how to get Id or xpath for elements in popup window for automate in python to enter username and password

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

how to get `Id` or `XPath` for elements in the popup window for automating in python selenium.
This is not an alert window.
Shell works only for the active window.

Please find the code below -

```
d = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\\Users\\ritasa\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (2)\\chromedriver.exe')
d.maximize_window()

d.get('itam9web.in.telstra.com.au/arsys')
hell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

d.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="details-button"]').click()
time.sleep(10)
d.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proceed-link"]').click()
time.sleep(10)
d.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="details-button"]').click()
time.sleep(10)
d.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proceed-link"]').click()
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Please share your code or the URL. This will be more helpful.

Comment: Hi,
d = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\\Users\\chromedriver_win32 (2)\\chromedriver.exe')
d.get('https://itam9web.in.com.au/arsys')
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')

d.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="details-button"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
d.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proceed-link"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
After this popup opens.
Not able to get id or xpath for popup field
So using shell
shell.Sendkeys("d921835")
time.sleep(2)
As shell works for active window, so automation can't work in background.
Need to get id of popup fields
Url work on client machine

Comment: Can someone please help . It would be great